# JQuery, Click only on the non-transparent area of a png

Tags: jquery, image, click, png, transparency

I know it's possible, but I would like a simple method that I can apply to all the elements that I want to generated ...

So I want to avoid:

- The map tags.
- Action Script.

I tried this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/GaEeG/2/ 
Works well but not on browsers tablets 
and its not working when multiple images are on each other.

```
Canvas can be?
```

I create a mask with the image in jpg and also by applying the mask I end up with a "transparant" clickable image?

it looks like this: 
http://m90.github.io/jquery-seeThru/static-alpha/ 
(jquery-SeeThru is only for video ...)

Is it possible?

Comment: Here is an example of what I want (which does not work) 
http://jsfiddle.net/yHk2u/3/

Answer (score 0):

After you get two days on a "simple" way to do what I wish I turned onto the image-map, when I have two images of one another I think this is the best way.

I used a [tutorial in French](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olKD4nAE81A) 
and this site generation [image-map](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html)

Also thank you to the person who made ​​me a -1 ... I started this site to get help .... not to punish me ...

And I apologize for my English which just google translation, English is not my native language.